# Wordpress Media Uploader events

Tags: uploads, events

I want to capture the click event on the "**Save all changes**" button?

Is there any callback method like there is when you click (**window.send_to_editor**) the "**Insert into Post**" button

[image: Here is a screenshot]

Comment: Could you maybe use jQuery to add an event listener to the save all changes button based on its class when the modal is opened?

Comment: how old is this WordPress version?

Comment: @seot I have seen this upload UI in newest versions of WP. It seems to still be available for plugins to use.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. You will have to use some local (browser-based) Javascript code to attach a function to the on-click event of the button.

(Not a Javascript expert, but perhaps this will point you in a direction of investigation.)

Answer (score 1):

You should got a class for that button
Try to find it and, if exists, you can fire event i.e using jQuery:

jQuery(".button-class").click(...);